# Retrieving of data from mysql returns the same for 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql, json

How do i encode this in json format? I am receiving the same data in my 1st, 2nd and 3rd if i put 1st, while if i put "2nd"=>$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZK8.jpg), "3rd"=>$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIZK8.jpg) the same data as the 1st is being retrieved. If i try to put in 3 it gives me a null. Please someone help, Thanks.

Here is my php

```
$sql = "select
  n_name,
  shortcut,
  case
    when rank = 1 then '1st'
    when rank = 2 then '2nd'
    when rank = 3 then '3rd'
  end as rank
from
  team inner join nonsport on team.n_id = nonsport.n_id group by n_name order by n_name asc";                         

 $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $response = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
array_push($response, array("n_name"=>$row[0], "1st"=>$row[1], "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[2]));
 }



echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));
```

My expected output is

Example. Shortcut has a, b, c and they have rank a =1 b =2 c =3;

Then 1st = a, 2nd = b, 3rd = c;

What im getting is

1st = a, 2nd = a, 3rd = a

[image: Tables]

Comment: you are assigning the same index multiple times, so it should give you the same result of course!! what are you trying to do? what is the expected output ??

Answer (score 0):

your query is returning 3 attributes for each row "n_name, shortcut, rank" and the rank will be "1st", "2nd", or "3rd", so you will not get the three ranks in a single row. I think you need to check the value of rank before assign it, as follow:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $array = [];
    $array["n_name"] = $row[0];

    if($row[1]=='a'){
        $array["1st"] = $row[1];
    } elseif($row[1]=='b'){
        $array["2nd"] = $row[1];
    } elseif($row[1]=='c'){
        $array["3rd"] = $row[1];
    }

    array_push($response, $array);
}
```

Comment: it only give me the n_name and nothing more sir

Comment: could you please share your tables?

Comment: posted a picture of the two tables sir